# How to convert a PDF file (contains text,images, may be interactive forms) to HTML string in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf-generation, quartz-core

Is there any way to convert PDF file which contains text,images & may be some interactive form to a html string?

By converting it to html string, I can display that file in WebView & achieve annotation & bookmark without third party library.

And convert that HTML back to PDF file.

Thanks

Comment: Have look on this Git repo - https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

You can load PDF file directly in UIWebView. Not only PDF, UIWebview supports multiple formats. So there is no need to convert it into html string.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Hi santosh, I want to achieve annotation, bookmark as well. And highlighting would be saved in the pdf file. I am not sure If I can achieve that by only loading pdf in web view. I suppose I will have to convert it to HTML string.